# How to access mysql database locally?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have xampp installed on ubuntu 16.04. The interface looks different from my windows installation of xampp on the same machine. I'm not sure how to use it. How do I access mysql database?

[image: XAMPP UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should do the work. In your browser type:

> http://localhost:port/phpmyadmin

Here is one solution according to your screenshot : 
https://blog.elijaa.org/2013/02/18/solve-wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writable-error-on-phpmyadmin/

And a similar post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923347/phpmyadmin-permissions-for-config-inc-php).

Comment: tried, but it doesn't work. this is what I get https://ibb.co/grWVi6

Answer (score 0):

Start xampp control. 
Start Apache 
Start mysql 
Click on "admin" on the right side of mysql. It opens a browser and enters in http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: mysql is turned on. I tried that, but it doesn't work. this is what I get https://ibb.co/grWVi6

Comment: Change the permissions....[sudo chmod 755 /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php]